# Sling event filtering

Tags: sling

Sling documentation has [Sling event handling details](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/how-to-manage-events-in-sling.html) however there is also support of sling Event Filtering which can be used, Is there any specific reason this is omitted in documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Apache Sling uses and exposes the OSGi Event Admin API package in order to support events. The implementation of the Event Admin API package is provided by the Apache Felix project, the OSGi Framework behind Apache Sling.

The ability to filter events is described in the OSGi specification (see the [org.osgi.service.event.EventConstants#EVENT_FILTER](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v41/org/osgi/service/event/EventConstants.html#EVENT_FILTER)) and an example of usage is provided in the Apache Felix documentation regarding [registering an event handler](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-event-admin.html#registering-an-event-handler).

The specific reason for omitting documenting the filtering feature in Apache Sling is likely that it is already documented in the respective project/specification.